# cpp windows application strange diagnostic messages

Tags: c++

I want to use this barcode reader  app to scan some barcodes in my cpp desktop application. The desktop app connects to an app on my phone and uses its camera to read barcodes and then sends its information to the desktop using wifi. I've managed to open the app and hide it.

The problem is im getting these strange messages from the app in my console window. [the messages im getting from the app in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnunE.jpg)

However, the app is doing its job, its scanning barcodes and data stream is being sent to the console window(saved as string a).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<winuser.h>
#include<tchar.h>

#include<shellapi.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a;
    HWND handle ;
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "C:\\Program Files\\Barcode to PC server\\Barcode to PC server.exe",NULL, NULL, SW_MINIMIZE )  ;
    handle = FindWindowA(NULL, "Barcode to PC server");
    ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
    for(int i=0 ; i<=4 ; i++)
    {
        cin>>a;
        cout<<"Scanned : "<<a<<endl<<endl;
    }

    DestroyWindow(handle);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post graphics that show text. Include the text in the question. Please check that the source cause is well formatted. You expected that somebody reads and understands your example. Don't make it hard to read if you expect ans answer. - click on *Edit* to change your question.

Comment: How is this code relevant to the messages? Don't you get them if you launch the server from the command line?

Comment: I doubt anybody here could guess how you got [Python code](https://github.com/fttx/barcode-to-pc-server/blob/a5142aeb75686c7d5c3e5fe387c0ef38ab6335d4/electron/src/handlers/connection.handler.ts#L100) in your app.